# Typed result from Azure mobile service with custom headers

Tags: .net, rest, azure, azure-mobile-services

When calling an Azure Mobile Service I would like to make a request to a custom REST service and pass my custom header values together and get a typed result back. Why don't I have that option? What am I missing?

Looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.invokeapiasync.aspx I can only provide custom headers when making an untyped request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload that takes additional headers wasn't added because of symmetry: in a typed scenario, you could specify headers for the request, but could not read the headers in the response (since the return type is the type T, which does not contain a header collection).

You can, however, use an extension method that does that, using a message handler that can be passed to the `MobileServiceClient` constructor. The code below is an example of such an implementation. It only implements two of the typed methods, but the implementation is trivial if you want to add the remaining ones.

```
class Program
{
    public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "https://YOUR-SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/",
        "YOUR-APPLICATION-KEY"
    );

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoWork().Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoWork()
    {
        var httpHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "x-header-1", "value 1" },
            { "x-header-2", "value 2" },
        };
        var test = await MobileService.InvokeApiWithHeaders<Test>("headers", httpHeaders);
        Console.WriteLine("Returned by the service:");
        foreach (var k in test.AllHeaderValues.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", k, test.AllHeaderValues[k]);
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> AllHeaderValues { get; set; }
}

public static class TypedInvokeApiWithHeadersExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> InvokeApiWithHeaders<T>(this MobileServiceClient client, string apiName, IDictionary<string, string> httpHeaders)
    {
        var client2 = new MobileServiceClient(client.ApplicationUri, client.ApplicationKey, new AddHeadersHandler(httpHeaders));
        return client2.InvokeApiAsync<T>(apiName);
    }

    public static Task<T> InvokeApiWithHeaders<T>(this MobileServiceClient client, string apiName, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> httpHeaders, IDictionary<string, string> queryParameters)
    {
        var client2 = new MobileServiceClient(client.ApplicationUri, client.ApplicationKey, new AddHeadersHandler(httpHeaders));
        return client2.InvokeApiAsync<T>(apiName, method, queryParameters);
    }

    class AddHeadersHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> headers;
        public AddHeadersHandler(IDictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            this.headers = headers;
        }
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice implementation!